# Internet usage when Remote Desktoped into a work computer

Tags: networking, internet, remote-desktop

I'm using a network extender (provided by my work) and remote desktop to connect to my work computer. Obviously streaming my work desktop to my home computer will use my internet connection, but if I search the internet on my work desktop, or download a large file from a network drive to my work computer, would it use my home internet or my work internet? Intuitively I would think that it should use my work internet because the file isn't leaving my work network, but I can't afford to be wrong.

Comment: this would use your work internet (and firewall and anti virus by the way). downloaded files however will land on your work computer, not your home's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct.

Anything you do within RDP will use your works internet connection.

All that goes down your connection is frames of the terminal in work. MS RDP is pretty efficient and usage is relatively low.